# MUI DataGrid Column Visibility-Show/Hide buttons - How can I identify whether show all/hide all was clicked?

Tags: material-ui, datagrid

I am using MaterialUI data grid pro in my React.js application. Certain columns are made visible:false by default. I am using the onColumnVisibilityModelChange event to handle the display of columns on click of the show all / hide all buttons in the columns menu. However the columns that are marked visible:false are not shown on click of the show all button. These columns also do not appear in the params for the onColumnVisibilityModelChange event.

I want to know whether there is a method available that will indicate whether Show All was clicked or Hide All was clicked. My logic here is to make the visible:false columns visible if Show all was clicked and to make them visible:false if Hide all is clicked.

The onColumnVisibilityModelChange event is called on click of both Show All and Hide All buttons, however I am not able to identify which of them was clicked.

[image: example image]

Checked the event parameter of onColumnVisibilityModelChange but it does not have a method or property that would tell whether Show All /Hide All button was clicked.